# sizing of plot with coord_fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot

```
  library(ggplot2)
   value = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,10,8,10,50,78),100,TRUE)
     data = data.frame(value = value)
     data$color = ifelse( data$value>.05 ,"red","blue")
     ggplot(data, aes(x =sort(value),y=sequence(table(value)))) + 
       geom_point(color = data[order(data$value),]$color  )
```

[image]

and I would like to make it more readable so I use `coord_fixed` to decrease the ratio but the plot shrinks.

Is there a way to make this more readable using `coord_fixed` or by smartly sizing the circles?

How would you smartly size the circles to make this look better, i.e. more readable while keeping the same size of the of the plot.

I needs to keep the same size because I am using `gridExtra` to combine this plot with others so the sizes must be the same.

I need to use this code not `geom_dotplot()` or anything else and it must work with arbitrary number of points.

```
   value = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,10,8,10,50,78),100,TRUE)
     data = data.frame(value = value)
     data$color = ifelse( data$value>.05 ,"red","blue")
     ggplot(data, aes(x =sort(value),y=sequence(table(value)))) + 
       geom_point(color = data[order(data$value),]$color  ) +coord_fixed(ratio=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please define "readable": what information exactly must be readable from the plot? What does "must work with arbitrary number of points" mean? Must this work just as well with either 100, 10^10 or 2 points?

Comment: I'd like the points to be closer together

Comment: geom_dotplot? Or just increase symbol size (size)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
value = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,10,8,10,50,78),100,TRUE)
## you can increase this to "squash down" the points along the vertical direction
squash.factor <- 0.8
data = data.frame(value = value)
data$color = ifelse( data$value>.05 ,"red","blue")
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=sort(value), y=sequence(table(value)))) + 
    geom_point(color = data[order(data$value),]$color  ) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(data$value), max(data$value)*squash.factor))
print(g)
```